# Work around for Android NuPlayer issues?

Tags: android, audio

I manage an SDK for Android devices.  My SDK provides audio playback functionality.

On the new S6 and S6Edge the NuPlayer is set as the Default, where as AwesomePlayer was the default on previous versions.

On the S6 with Default Configurations this:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fd, 0, mediaFile.length()); // fine

mediaPlayer.prepare() // fails
```

The behavior at this point is that the audio basically plays twice (with a small offset), or with a delay, so while its still understandable it sounds very weird.

If I disable NuPlayer (or enable AwesomePlayer, this option is different on the S6/S6Edge) then everything works fine.

I can't manually disable the NuPlayer on every device with this configuration, are there any work arounds for these NuPlayer bugs?

Comment: Did you ever find anything? Is there a way to programmatically say you want to use AwesomePlayer instead of NuPlayer?

Comment: nope.I believe switching the file format to mp3 helped some?  I'm not longer in that position and don't fully recall what we did.

Comment: I actually need gapless video playback. One time that nuplayer errored out I believe it fell back on AwesomePlayer or StageFright and it became gapless.